# how to set properly ymax and ytick

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying a plot the left y-axis from 0.5 to 0.88 with 0.88 at the top border of the box (like the 160 at the 2nd y-axis).

But even to get 0.88 I have to set ymax and (the last ytick) to 0.9 and it's still not at the top!

Why is this?

Why do I have set ymax and ytick 0.02 points further then the number I would like to have?
And why isn't the number at the top?

I really don't know what's the problem!

Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,
            paper=a4,
            twoside=false,
                    ]{scrreprt}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9,                        
        /pgf/number format/1000 sep={},     
        /pgf/number format/use comma,       
        }
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}          
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}                     

\begin{document}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
%
\pgfplotsset{set layers,            
        ticklabel shift={0.05cm}}       
%
\begin{axis}[width=0.8\textwidth,
            grid=major,
            ymin = 0.5,
            ymax = 0.9,
            ytick={0.5,0.52,...,0.9},
            y tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed,/pgf/number format/fixed zerofill=true,/pgf/number format/precision=2},    
            axis y line*=left,
            ylabel={voltage},
            y unit=\si{\volt},
            xlabel={time},
            x unit = \si{\minute},
            xtick={0,5,...,75},
            xmin = 0,
            xmax = 75,
            ]
%
\end{axis}
%
\begin{axis}[width=0.8\textwidth,
            %grid=major,
            %/pgf/number format/precision=3,
            legend style={legend columns=-1,anchor=north},
            legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)}},
            %legend cell align=left,
            ymin = 0,
            ymax = 160, 
            %ytick={0,10,...,160},
            axis y line*=right,
            xlabel={time},
            x unit = \si{\minute},
            xtick={0,5,...,75},
            xmin = 0,
            xmax = 75,
            axis x line=none,
            ylabel={current},
            y unit= \si{\ampere},
            ]
%               
%
\end{axis}
%
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
```

After further investigation I was able to figure out the problem.

It seems that setting `ymin` and `ymax` and additionally `ytick={...}` causes the problem.

`ytick={...}` seems (sometimes) to work differently dependent on the definition.

Here's a MWE with the behaviour and an explanation:

`ymax` and `ymin` are `0.5` and `1` and I would like to have `0.05` steps at the y-axis.

If I only define `ymin=0.5` and `ymax=1` the ticks at the y-axis are 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, ..., 1.0. But that's not what I want.

So instead of using `ymin` and `ymax` I define `ytick={0.5, 0.55, ..., 1}`. But then the ticks at the y-axis are only from 0.55 to 0.95. So the first and the last one are being ignored.

If I only define `ytick={0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1}` then only the first tick is being ignored. So the ticks at the y-axis are from 0.55 to 1.

Therefore, defining `ymin=0.5` and `ymax=1` and additionally `ytick={0.5, 0.55, ..., 1}` prevents the last y-tick 1.0 from being printed!

And that's my problem. I want to have 0.5 to 1 with 0.05 steps. But specifying these additionally with `ytick={0.5, 0.55, ..., 1}` it only prints until 0.95.

What I'm doing now is defining `ymin=0.5`, `ymax=1` and `ytick={0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1}` to get the right divisions and all the ticks.

I don't know if it's really a problem or if I simply don't understand the behaviour of setting up `ymax` and `ymin` and additionally `ytick={...}`?!?!

Any ideas to avoid defining all the y-ticks or an explanation how the set up the y-ticks properly are very welcome!

MWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,
        paper=a4,
        twoside=false,
                 ]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9,
     /pgf/number format/1000 sep={},
     /pgf/number format/use comma,
     enlargelimits=false,
     }

\begin{document}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{axis}[grid=major,
        xlabel ={time /min},
        xtick={0,10,...,60},
        xmin = 0,
        xmax = 60,
        ylabel = {voltage /V},
        ymin = 0.5,
        ymax = 1,
        %ytick={0.5,0.55,...,1},   %<-- first and last ytick is being ignored
        %ytick={0.5,0.55,0.6,0.65,0.7,0.75,0.8,0.85,0.9,0.95,1}  %<-- first ytick is being ignored
        ]
        \addplot[color=red,no marks] coordinates{(0,0.52)(10,0.75)(20,0.85)(30,1)(40,0.85)(50,0.75)(60,0.55)};
\end{axis}
%
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Add `enlargelimits=false` to the `\pgfplotsset` options. There is a default enlarging action in place.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work!

Comment: Works for me though.

Comment: @AdamLiter
Because it was so much additional information, I wasn't sure if it's ok to edit question.

So I did add the answer as additional information to the question and tried to delete my own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, before I commented I changed a few things at once. It is still possible to have a solution but here the main problem is how `\foreach` produces arrays.

First of all, `pgfplots` checks the min and max data so in your example there is nothing drawn inside the axis so takes the interval `[0,1]`. Without data, it will still be this interval no matter what you provide. I don't know if this a feature or something overrides a setting.

---

When `\foreach` starts reading the increment in the dotted syntax, it starts adding the increment to the initial point and if it goes beyond last point it discards it, say,

```
\foreach\x in{1,2,...,4.9}{\x}
```

will give `1234`. So it has to hit something below the last number or exactly the last number.

Here is a compactified version of your problem. See how the numbers get contaminated by TeX arithmetic.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
            ymin = 0.5,
            ymax = 0.88,
            y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,fixed zerofill=true,precision=6},
            ytick={0.5,0.52,...,0.88},
            ]\addplot {0.7 + (rand)/10};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The easiest solution is to shift the end point ever so slightly, say, `0.8801` and then you'll hit that point.

A possible solution is to implement the `\foreach` within axis environment with `fpu` enabled but it looks like quite some work.

[image]